# Verification not working for Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is designed to make an element sticky when it reaches a specific point on the page.  That is working correctly, however on some pages that section doesn't exist (by design).  As a result I am getting an Uncaught TypeError.  I have tried a few methods of verifying the `var` but it's still not working correctly on pages without the JumpTo div.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var jumpToTop = jQuery(".jump-to").offset().top - 160;
    if (jumpToTop !== undefined) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > jumpToTop) {
                jQuery(".jump-to").addClass("sticky-jump-to");
            } else {
                jQuery(".jump-to").removeClass("sticky-jump-to");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please help me with the verification or other method so that the function only runs when `.jump-to` is present and I don't get the Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: Store the `.jump-to` in a var and check it:  `var jt = $(".jump-to"); if (jt.length === 0) return;` (then use `jt` instead of `$(".jump-to")`)  (or just check it directly if you're not bothered about tiny performance gains)

Comment: @freedomn-m - I simply started with `if (jQuery(".jump-to").length)` and that did the trick